# How many random / sequential access per fread / fwrite?

Tags: c++, fread

I have the following question regarding C file I/O.

At a physical level (harddrive), is it valid to assume that every `fread(n_blocks, size, length,FILE fp)` operation should cost one random access for the first page (block) and n-1 sequential accesses for the next blocks of that same buffer ??

I assumed this because the OS has so many processes that is mostly sure that one of them is also writing to or reading from a file between each `fread` of the local program and by that assumption the hard drive is positioned at another sector / cylinder.

is ok this assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you assume that or not, this is a gross oversimplification of the reality.

First thing first: you seem to think that the 3rd parameter (`length`) corresponds to the number of some discrete 'access operations'. This is not the case. All `fread` does is to read `size*length` bytes; thus the following three calls do the exact same thing, as long as the multiplication doesn't overflow:

```
fread(n_blocks, size, length, fp);
fread(n_blocks, size*length, 1, fp);
fread(n_blocks, 1, size*length, fp);
```

What **actually** happens, is that `fread/fwrite` will read and write to/from an internal buffer in the memory of *your process*. That buffer can be controlled with the `setbuf/setvbuf` functions. When the buffer is full/empty, they will forward the read/write to the *operating system*, which has its own file cache. If you are reading and the OS can't find the portion of the file in the cache then your program will wait until the data is actually fetched from the drive. When writing, the data will be copied to the OS cache and reside there until the OS decides to write it to the drive, which may happen long after your program has closed the file and existed. In turn, today's hard drives have their own internal caches which the OS may not even be aware of.

For all practical purposes, you should not concern yourself with how many drive accesses each `fread/fwrite` call does. Just know that C, the OS, and the hardware underneath will do their best to provide the requested data as fast as possible. However, keep in mind that this entire stack *is* optimized for sequential access. So avoid jumping all around the file with `fseek` for no good reason.

Comment: i start to understand the complexity hidden in I/O. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. The blocks of a single file may be scattered all over the hard disk if the filesystem is [fragmented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29).

Comment: you are right. Another thing that got me was that Some websites claim that consecutive reads give sequential access to speedup, that should also be a wrong asumption, unless they assume an ideal enviroment with no other i/o processes?

Comment: @Cristobal: they probably assume that the file in question is stored contiguously. Modern filesystems do try to uphold that promise, though they're not perfect in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. You can't even assume that an  `fread` will trigger physical I/O. Your OS has the possibility to do a lot of stuff with I/O requests, including caching the results, reordering and coalescing (or splitting) reads (and even sometimes writes).

If there is a lot of I/O going on, you can't count on getting sequential reads either, depending on what size buffer you (and possibly the I/O stream library) use. Some operating systems provide ways to "hint" that you will be reading sequentially on a file descriptor (or `mmap`ed region) which could help.

Comment: thanks for fast answer. I wonder how could i get the information of how many sequential and random access im doing in a C program i have.

Comment: The C language itself doesn't provide anything for that. You'll need to look at system-dependent I/O tracing tools or APIs for that.

Answer (score 1):

From the point view of an application programmer, the exact process of reading the blocks is indeterministic. It all goes down to the disk scheduler that organizes the access operations of multiple requests at the same time from multiple processes. [There are multiple algorithms to solve this issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDisk_scheduling_algorithms), but thinking too simplistic(1 random seek, n sequential seeks) is not realistic at all. In the end, neither the C standard nor the C++ standard define such a thing for clear reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As many explained, caching (perhaps at several levels) has to be taken into account.

Perhaps you want to know how to accelerate or tune it from your C code. This is highly operating system specific.

On recent Linux systems, you could use the [readahead](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead), [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) (with [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)) and others system calls.

Often, you can simply [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) in advance a file (perhaps just with `cat yourfile > /dev/null`) and your program would then run faster on Linux.

Try for instance running twice the `wc` word counting utility on some big file. The second run usually goes much faster than the first.